# How to set Symfony request while it is wrapped as Behat request object?

Tags: symfony, testing, request, behat

I was trying to use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request->attributes->set('token', 123);` when it is wrapped as `Behatch\HttpCall\Request`,
but there is no attributes for the behatch object, there are only `setHeader()`, `setServerParameter()`, but these are not what I want,
and the getRequest() for the raw Symfony request is protected too,
So for this case how to set the attributes of Symfony request?